# retrieve certain fields from a table using a column value where table name is unknown

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets

I am trying to get the cost and itemno of a product which I get dynamically from the user in a `jsp`. I am using data from three tables from which the user can choose the product. So all I know will be the product name which can be present in any of these three tables so basically i wouldn't know the table name. I am passing the product to a `servlet` where i want to display the product along with its `cost` and `itemno`. I used the following query but i get only an error message

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery
("SELECT * FROM indi.COLUMNS WHERE column_name ='" +  previousItems + "');");
```

where inde is the schema name and previousitem is the product name which i get dynamically from the user in a jsp. I get the error message as sql syntax wrong. The following is the error message

> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>           Table 'indi.columns' doesn't exist

Comment: Is your table name is exact one ? What is the table in DB? Error clearly says that table doesnt exist

Comment: why don't you just query your three tables one by one?

Comment: If you know the columnname then you can fetch the tablename from information_schema. After fetching the tablename, you can fire your above mentioned query with tablename in it. But remember, there can be more than one table having the columnname that you are specifying. Find a work-around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve some column value where you dont know column name
there is a command for column name ,it will give you all column name of existing table

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('COLOM_NAME_TO_SEARCH')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';
```

I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can table names by this query:

```
SELECT
    `TABLE_NAME`
FROM 
    `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE
    `TABLE_SCHEMA` = [DATABASE_NAME]
```

Then you can query each table...